# DRBD Not starting on Fresh AWS 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, drbd

I followed these instructions precisely (I've done this from scratch using 11.04 and 11.10 with the same results using AMI's )

(using 11.04) Community AMI: ami-e016ca89
https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/drbd.html
and 
(using 11.10) Community AMI: ami-baba68d3
https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/drbd.html

I am getting the following error when starting the process:

```
root@drbd01:~# sudo /etc/init.d/drbd start
 * Starting DRBD resources                                                                                            Can not load the drbd module.
```

Created a volume (on both versions) 250gb Volume, attached as /dev/xvdm

Here is my config file:

```
global { usage-count no; }
common { syncer { rate 100M; } }
resource r0 {
        protocol C;
        startup {
                wfc-timeout  15;
                degr-wfc-timeout 60;
        }
        net {
                cram-hmac-alg sha1;
                shared-secret "secret";
        }
        on drbd01 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk xvdm;
                address -MY AWS PUBLIC ELASTIC IP WAS HERE-:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        on drbd02 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/xvdm;
                address -MY AWS PUBLIC ELASTIC IP WAS HERE-:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, your kernel does not have the drbd module - confirm by trying to add it: `modprobe -v drbd` (which will fail, if the kernel doesn't have it). You can also try: `modprobe -l | grep drbd`. It is possible that Ubuntu offers drdb as a loadable kernel module - but I am not familiar enough with it to offer any next steps. (I can confirm that it is not an issue with EC2 - as Amazon's Linux does in fact include the drbd module as part of its kernel).

Comment: Looks like I am missing it... root@drbd01:~# modprobe -v drbd
FATAL: Module drbd not found.

Comment: With your comment details, I found this and it worked perfectly, thanks for the info!

$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
$ sudo depmod -a
$ sudo modprobe drbd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With cyberx86's help, I did a search and found this, which works.

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
$ sudo depmod -a
$ sudo modprobe drbd
```

Cite: http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-cloud@lists.ubuntu.com/msg00588.html